# mongoose findOne method returns null but data exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

### my process

nickname button click (React) => nickname check (mongoose: findOne)

#### 1. if nickname is duplicated

return dup message

#### 2. if nickname is not duplicated

nickname update (mongoose: findOneAndUpdate)

---

### my problem

#### this code worked as I expected.

```js
app.patch('/user/:mid', async (req, res) => {
    const targetUser = await usersModel.findOne({ nickname: req.body.nickname })

    if (targetUser) {
      console.log('dup')
    } 

    else {
      console.log('no dup')
    }
})
```

#### this code didn't work

```js
app.patch('/user/:mid', async (req, res) => {
    const targetUser = await usersModel.findOne({ nickname: req.body.nickname })

    if (targetUser) {
      console.log('dup')
      res.json({ message: 'Duplicate nickname' })
    } 

    else {
      await usersModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.mid },
        { nickname: req.body.nickname },
      )
      console.log('no dup')
      res.json({ message: 'Nickname updated successfully' })
    }
})
```

Here is my question.
mongoose doesn't support two methods in one api?

I commented second method `findOneAndUpdate()` then worked.
but I expected find nickname and findOneAndUpdate.

please help!

Comment: One of the common causes of query failure is datatype mismatch. You may have been querying an ObjectId field with string input.

Comment: @ray I understand what you're saying, but it's weird to not find duplicate data in the first attempt and to find duplicate data in the second attempt. The first attempt and the second attempt are not trying to change the data, but just pressing the same button twice.

Comment: "*mongoose doesn't support two methods in one api*?" It's actually Express that is the API in your case and you can use as many mongoose queries as you want within each Express route handler until you return a response. You have no error handling so you don't know if the `findOneAndUpdate` fails and you don't store the resolved result of that method in a variable so you can't check if it's `null` or not. I suspect `req.params.mid` is not what you think it is. I can make some coding suggestions to help you if you want?

Comment: @jQueeny If you don't mind, please suggest it. But when I send the same req.params.mid, I get a different result. For example, there is a person with the nickname apple, and when I first clicked on the save button, there was no duplication, so I checked that the save was completed with that value and that it was actually changed. But when I clicked the second time, it said there was a duplication, so I confirmed that the message of duplication was returned. Which part should I change? If necessary, I will provide you with other parts of the source as well.

Comment: If you post your user schema I will give an example of how this is typically done using a unique index on the `nickname` property of your document. This way you can just do one operation (an update) and mongodb will ensure each nickname is unique.

Comment: as @jQueeny said, provide the user schema. and what do you mean by *this code didn't work*, 1. an error, or 2. it didn't update the nickname even if there was no dup, or 3.  it updated the nickname even if there was a dup ?

Answer (score -1):

> Here is my question. mongoose doesn't support two methods in one api?

No, mongoose does support two (or more) method calls in a controller.

if you want to insert a new nickname (doc) when nickname doesn't exist on the database, then you have to specify the upsert option

**ex:**

```js
app.patch('/user/:mid', async (req, res) => {
    
    // ...
    else {
        
        await ColorModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: req.params.mid },
            { nickname: req.body.nickname }, 
            { upsert: true } // set upsert option to true
        )
        console.log('no dup')
        res.json({ message: 'Nickname inserted successfully' })
    }
})
```

**Edit:** reading your code, i tried to make sense of what you wanted to do, that's why my previous answer was that you might be wanting to insert a new doc.

now explaining your logic:

when you hit the patch route (i.e. `/user/:mid`), `findOne` returns an single doc when nickname exists in the whole database.

when `targetUser` has a doc/value, if/else condition will run (but else block codes will not execute) and sends `{message: 'Duplicate nickname'}` json as response.

but if nickname doesn't exists in the whole database then `findOne` will return null, thus if/else condition will not run. your nickname field will not update because codes inside else block didn't run.

**tl;dr:** your query/logic/english is f*cked up.

either your `req.body.nickname` doesn't have a value or has wrong value. you didn't say what are you using to send the the data. you are either using fetch or just plain html form.

when sending data by plain html form, you need to use `urlencoded` middleware but when you are sending data with fetch you will need to use `json` middleware to pharse the `req.body`